# Android - How can i use events of extra physical buttons like pressy

Tags: android

I want to use an extra physical button in my app. It is connected to the ear phones plug. I searched the web and didn't find specific answers. Maybe i didnt use the correct search terms? 
Are there any tutorials available?
What events are triggered when such a button is pressed?
Is there any difference (in coding) between the original pressy and the cheap china things? 
Is it possible to emulate this thing in the adk emulator?

I really want to use this thing in my app, but i dont have a clue how.
I need some help to get started
Any ideas?

Youre answer's helped me to get startet.

Now im am facing new problems, as the toasts i'll try to make to check the responses dont appear. Button press will just play and pause music with the samsung music player on the phone.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver; 
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MediaButtonIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public MediaButtonIntentReceiver() {
  super();
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  String intentAction = intent.getAction();
  Toast.makeText(context, "onRecieve triggered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
    return;
  }
  KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
  if (event == null) {
    return;
  }

  int action = event.getAction();
  Toast.makeText(context, "Action lauchched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
  // do something
    Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON PRESSED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
  }
  if (action == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE) {
    // do something
    Toast.makeText(context, "Play Pause pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
  }
 abortBroadcast();
}
}
```

so it seems that the reciever code isnt reached.
in my activity there are following lines:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  SharedPreferences prefs =    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ZaehlenActivity.this);
  setContentView(R.layout.zaehlen);

  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
  MediaButtonIntentReceiver r = new MediaButtonIntentReceiver();
  registerReceiver(r, filter);
```

am i forgettig something? do i have to disable the standard earphone recognition somehow?

Comment: I think the first question should be: What is a "pressy" ? :S **Edit** Have just researched "Pressy", so it's an external media button in effect.

Comment: Hi Marco pls check my answer , If you have a trouble in implementing it just add a comment I'm gonna help you

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, this really got me started. I dont know if i can upvote both your answers...

Comment: My Rep is not high enough for upvoting, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that earphone buttons are considered as `MEDIA_BUTTONS` so , you have to create a `BroadcastReceiver` which listen to `android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON` and make a test statment to test if the action is an `ACTION_DOWN` , here's a suite of code it may helps :

This is the `BroadcastReceiver`which you have to declare it in AndroidManifest.xml , and make as Intent-filter : `android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON`

```
public class MediaButtonIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public MediaButtonIntentReceiver() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String intentAction = intent.getAction();
    if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
        return;
    }
    KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
    if (event == null) {
        return;
    }
    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    // do something
        Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON PRESSED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
    abortBroadcast();
}
}
```

And this is an `Activity` which listen to the `BroadcastReceiver`and then make a `Toast`if one of the buttons was clicked :

```
public class mainActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    MediaButtonIntentReceiver r = new MediaButtonIntentReceiver();
    registerReceiver(r, filter); 

}
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: It doesnt seem to react to the reciever. I did as you wrote here and added the lines to the manifest like written by LokiSinclair. But it seems the pressy thing still works as an earphone. I dont get toasts on klicking the pressy thing. i'll putt  some code above.

Comment: This also works for Smart Button from Chine with KlicK appication (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.helloklick.android). Thank you!

Comment: There is only one problem, it is working on HTC Desire 500, Android 4.1.2, but it is not working on Nexus 5x, Android 7.1.2. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as Pressy is an external controller (so to speak), you'll need to use a `BroadcastReceiver` with an intent-filter for: `android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON` So, for example:

Inside your AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver android:name="RemoteControlReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And your new receiver class:

```
public class RemoteControlReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // handle media button here
            KeyEvent key = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            // handle keydown etc 
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to check single buttons (maybe on a cabled device, such as headphones, or wireless like Bluetooth), you could also use the `onKeyDown` and check for `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_SOMEKEYIDENTIFIER` Like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    switch(keyCode){
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD:
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT:
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS:
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_REWIND:
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP:
            return true;

        // etc etc...
    }

    return false;
}
```

Hope this at least gets you started. Cheers.

Comment: This was some time ago now, its likely that Android updates have changed how this works.