# Android Smart Button in headphone connector

Tags: android, button

I bought from local eshop device called "[Android Smart Button](http://www.helloklick.com/index.php/site/download)". It is similar to Pressy, but I didn´t know that it is from Chine including application. When I tried to download app, Google Chrome warned me that it is not safe. So I would like to program own application to control it, but I do not know, when I can receive button click. Can you advice me? Thank you.

I tried this, but it did not work.

```
<receiver android:name=".RemoteControlReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: ");
if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    KeyEvent event = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I found [solution provided by Fouad Wahabi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25546084/android-how-can-i-use-events-of-extra-physical-buttons-like-pressy/25546414#25546414) and it also works for this Smart Button from Chine. So now I can finally replace very untrusted application called [KlicK](http://%22https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.helloklick.android%22).